# C# lambda, Select .Distinct() or GroupBy() for month only?

Tags: c#, lambda, linq-to-objects

I have the following

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataX dx = new DataX();
    List<Excursion> lstExcur = new List<Excursion>();
    lstExcur = dx.GetAllExcursions();
    rptExcursionOuter.DataSource = lstExcur.Distinct(x => x.StartDate.Month); 
    rptExcursionOuter.DataBind();
}
protected void rptExcursionOuter_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        if (e.Item.DataItem != null)
        {
            Excursion Ritem = (Excursion)e.Item.DataItem;//<---- this bit errors, is there a way to keep the object intact but group or distinct by month?
            Literal LitExcursionMonth = (Literal)e.Item.FindControl("LitExcursionMonth");
            LitExcursionMonth.Text = Ritem.StartDate.ToString("MMMM");
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way i can GroupBy or Distinctly select by month but have it retunr the object so i can get to the itemdatabound dataitem?
Any help would be greatly apreciated.

Comment: what data item would you expect? Just any arbitrary one per group?

Comment: So if two excursions have the same month, which one do you want to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First do the `GroupBy`to get an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, Excursion>>` where the `int` is `Excursion.StartDate.Month`:

```
 rptExcursionOuter.DataSource = lstExcur.GroupBy(x => x.StartDate.Month, x => x)
                                        .OrderBy(g => g.First().StartDate.Month);
```

Change the method below:

```
protected void rptExcursionOuter_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        if (e.Item.DataItem != null)
        {
            var itemsByMonth = (IGrouping<int, Excursion>)e.Item.DataItem;
            Literal LitExcursionMonth = (Literal)e.Item.FindControl("LitExcursionMonth");
            LitExcursionMonth.Text = itemsByMonth.First().StartDate.ToString("MMMM");
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE: Added the OrderBy**

Comment: i get 'specified cast not valid' error on line - var itemsByMonth = (KeyValuePair<int, IEnumerable<Excursion>>)e.Item.DataItem;

Comment: Ah nice one Ed that working great, is there a way i can order them by month asc?